# pitch returned by getOrientation function is wrong

Tags: android, matrix, geometry, android-sensors

The old `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` sensor returned a pitch between -180° and 180°. This was a nice API which included filtering and worked great. Sadly `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` was deprecated and is not available on modern phones.

The blessed replacement for `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is a complicated combination of `Context.SENSOR_SERVICE` and `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and the `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()` and `SensorManager.getOrientation()` functions. You're on your own when it comes to filtering. (As an aside I used [iirj](https://github.com/berndporr/iirj) - the trivial low pass filters I found on Stackoverflow did not work as well as whatever `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` did)

The documentation for [getOrientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) claims that it returns a pitch between -π to π. This can't be true since the implementation is `values[1] = (float) Math.asin(-R[7]);` (`asin` returns values between -π/2 and π/2)

Is there any way to get the full 360° of pitch and roll from the rotation matrix?

Comment: This was reported as a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127944

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37127944) that Google won't fix. I created my own `getOrientation` function based on [Gregory G. Slabaugh's paper](http://%20http://www.close-range.com/docs/Computing_Euler_angles_from_a_rotation_matrix.pdf)

```
// Based on pseudo code from http://www.close-range.com/docs/Computing_Euler_angles_from_a_rotation_matrix.pdf
object EulerAngleHelper {
    private const val R11 = 0
    private const val R12 = 1
    private const val R13 = 2
    private const val R21 = 3
    private const val R22 = 4
    private const val R23 = 5
    private const val R31 = 6
    private const val R32 = 7
    private const val R33 = 8
    private const val AZIMUTH = 0
    private const val PITCH = 1
    private const val ROLL = 2
    private const val PHI_Z = AZIMUTH
    private const val PSI_X = PITCH
    private const val THETA_Y = ROLL

    fun getOrientation(r: DoubleArray, values: DoubleArray): DoubleArray {
        when {
            r[R31] < -0.98 -> {
                values[PHI_Z] = 0.0 // Anything; can set to 0
                values[THETA_Y] = Math.PI / 2
                values[PSI_X] = values[PHI_Z] + atan2(r[R12], r[R13])
            }
            r[R31] > 0.98 -> {
                values[PHI_Z] = 0.0 // Anything; can set to 0
                values[THETA_Y] = -Math.PI / 2
                values[PSI_X] = values[PHI_Z] + atan2(-r[R12], -r[R13])
            }
            else -> {
                values[THETA_Y] = -asin(r[R31])
                val cosTheta = cos(values[THETA_Y])
                values[PSI_X] = atan2(r[R32] / cosTheta, r[R33] / cosTheta)
                values[PHI_Z] = atan2(r[R21] / cosTheta, r[R11] / cosTheta)
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

I've only tested the pitch and roll.